# Calculating the difference between two dates using age and extract gives differing results in Postgresql

Tags: date, amazon-redshift

I'm using Postgresql (on Amazon Redshift), and I need to calculate the difference between two dates and then use that value in a formula to compute a ratio, so the date difference needs to be translated to a numeric value, preferably a float or double precision.

I have two dates: 1/1/2017 and 1/1/2014.  I need to find the difference between these two dates in number of days.

When I use the age function I get 1080 days:

```
select age('2017-01-01','2014-01-01')
```

However, since age returns an interval and I need to work with a numeric result, I am using EXTRACT to convert the final value.  I chose epoch since I wasn't able to find any other value for EXTRACT that would yield the number of time units between the two dates.  This formula yields 1095.75 days (the divisor is the number of seconds in a day):

```
select extract(epoch from age('2017-01-01','2014-01-01'))/86400
```

Why am I getting a difference of 19.75 days when using age vs using extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1080 is the figure you would get if every month was 30 days long (36 months by 30 days equals 1080), as it would be if you used `justify_days` (either explicitly or if the DBMS called it implicitly). You don't say *how* you're getting this 1080 figure since I believe the duration would normally just print out something like `3 years`, but that seems the most likely case

1095.75 seems the more correct figure, being 365.25 days multiplied by three years.

Out of those two, I would go with the latter method.

Although, as pointed out at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT, calculating the difference between two date types should yield the number of days:

```
select dtend - dtstart from somewhere
```

Answer (score 5):

Did you try

```
select '2017-01-01'::date - '2014-01-01'::date;
```

The difference between two `date`s is number of days in integer

Answer (score 0):

Redshift release notes say they recently released a months between function which looks similar to oracles  months between function if that's what you're looking for. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_MONTHS_BETWEEN_function.html